# Self moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm interested in knowing how is the self moderation system implemented for askubuntu. It's very much like the one on stack overflow, or OpenERP. Is there a CMS, or framework including this functionality as standard?
I wanna implement something like that on a forum and that would be a great help.
Thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: I think you're asking about the same in your earlier question. [What's this site designed with?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6456/88802)

Answer (score 3):

Ask Ubuntu is run by Stack Exchange, Inc. (which also run Stack Overflow and [about 90 other sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites). The software itself is closed source, but there are plenty of [alternatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) that strive to achieve the same effect of Stack Exchange platform.