# What's this site designed with?

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in knowing how this site is built? I'm particularly interested in the self moderation system. I's very much like the one on stack overflow, or OpenERP. Is there a CMS, or framework including this functionality as standard?
I wanna implement something like that on a forum and that would be a great help.
Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask Ubuntu is designed with the [Stack Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_exchange) framework.

There is actually a Stack Exchange site dedicated to creating new Stack Exchange sites, called [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_exchange). Keep in mind that Stack Exchange sites are a community effort, however, and that creating your own for a forum may involve a little more work.